# query to determine if someone has voted on an idea

Tags: apex, soql

I'm using the standard idea object to post ideas and have users promote/demote ideas.  How can you query an idea record to determine if a user has voted on the idea?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Vote sObject. Your query might look something like this:

```
List<Vote> userVote = [SELECT CreatedById, ParentId FROM Vote WHERE CreatedById = :UserId AND ParentId = :IdeaId]
```

obviously replacing the Ids appropriately in the where clause. You could then check if this list's size is 0 or not to determine if a given user voted.

Comment: your query is not correct.

Comment: Fixed. The query was written as borderline pseudocode as I didn't check if it was syntactically correct. I presume the OP understood the gist of what I was suggesting

Comment: Is there a way to just get all Votes for a given user id?

Comment: Just remove the "AND ParentId = :IdeaId" part of the where clause

Answer (score 0):

`List<Vote> lstVote = [SELECT Type FROM Vote WHERE CreatedById =: UserId AND ParentId =: IdeaId];`

This query will work , what is asked in question.