# DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: duplicates value on record with id

Tags: apex

Inserting Vote:

```
    vote v=new Vote();
    v.Type='down';
    v.parentId='0875w000000QYlZ'; //passing Idea Id
     insert v;
    system.debug('v-'+v.id);
```

Error:

**System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found:  duplicates value on record with id: : []**

Q2; How  to user query upcount and down count of the Idea. In which object details it resides?

In idea level,**can able to see vote total and vote score not upcount and downcount**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @Annappa PH it looks like it's because that user (the running user presumably) has already voted on that idea. If this is a unit test you'd likely need to create another user and do a `System.runAs(newUser)`.

If this is live logic, you'd need to first do a query to check if the user has already voted: [[query to determine if someone has voted on an idea](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/query-to-determine-if-someone-has-voted-on-an-idea/66966][1])

```
List<Vote> userVote = [SELECT CreatedById, ParentId FROM Vote WHERE CreatedById = :UserId AND ParentId = :IdeaId]
```

For your second question, you could also just use the same query, adding the `Type` field to your query to indicate up or down. Or to your point if you want it on Idea level, utilize the `VoteScore` field on an `Idea` soql query.